# When I run `./manage.py runserver`, it starts two processes. How to enable interprocess data sharing and interprocess calls?

Tags: python, django, apscheduler

I also use `apscheduler` lib inside the `Django` webserver handler. I want to create a single instance of `apscheduler` and communicate all calls to it.

Is the best solution to create a different process specifically designated for `apscheduler` instance?

A similar questions are [1] and [2].

[1] [How to enforce only one running instance of a process in python Django framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51996912/how-to-enforce-only-one-running-instance-of-a-process-in-python-django-framework)

[2] [Make sure only one worker launches the apscheduler event in a pyramid web app running multiple workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053364/make-sure-only-one-worker-launches-the-apscheduler-event-in-a-pyramid-web-app-ru)

Answer (score 0):

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40162246/529442 has a good overview of `Gunicorn` way for this which probably could help.